# Auto fold sections on startup

Tags: sectioning

I am working on a large document in TeXstudio and always become a bit daunted when i see the wall of text in the document. The first thing I do then is to fold all sections in the document to get a better view. It is a bit annoying however to fold all the sections manually everytime i open the document. Is there a way in TeXstudio to auto fold all sections on startup?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: If all you want is getting a good overview of the sectional units, try inserting a (temporary) table of contents.